# Passbook , showing an .pass in an app

Tags: swift, passkit

All, 
I have been reading from Apple documentation and I have found info to show bits of a pass and changing a pass in an app. But is there a way the .pass zip can be stored in XCODE and shown in a pop up view controller ?

I have figured this out, but I doesnt work.

Any advice ??

```
var pkfile : NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: "Event.pkpass")!
        var pass : PKPass = PKPass(data: pkfile, error: nil)
        let vc = PKAddPassesViewController(pass: pass)
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 7):

I have done it like this :

```
 var filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Event", ofType:"pkpass")
        var pkfile : NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath!)!
        var pass : PKPass = PKPass(data: pkfile, error: nil)
        let vc = PKAddPassesViewController(pass: pass) as PKAddPassesViewController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and made sure that the pkpass file is set in build Settings/Copy Bundle Resources.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Just a note: For this to work it seems that the data param needs to be NSData using the newer Data class returns an error that the .pkpass file can't be opened.

Answer (score 4):

For Swift 4

```
if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "BoardingPass", ofType: "pkpass") {
    let pkfile : NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: filepath)!
    let pass : PKPass = PKPass(data: pkfile as Data, error: nil)
    let vc = PKAddPassesViewController(pass: pass) as PKAddPassesViewController
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
} else {
    print("Boarding pass not found.")
}
```

Comment: Xcode is complaining now that `PKPass = PKPass(data: pkfile as Data, error: nil)` does not take a second parameter.  @faran-rasheed post below does the job

Comment: I'd improve the readability, eg call pkfile fileData and remove more obsolete code, but then I'd just work for Copilot without getting paid.

Answer (score 2):

```
    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "BoardingPass", ofType: "pkpass")
    let pkfile : NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath!)!

    do {
        let pass = try PKPass(data: pkfile as Data)
        let vc = PKAddPassesViewController(pass: pass)
        self.present(vc!, animated: true)
    }
    catch {
        print("something went wrong!")
    }
```